# How can I see maven's parallel build graph

Tags: maven, maven-3, parallel-builds

[Parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) in Maven 3 are a good thing.

The process uses dependency graph to evaluate the order of builds, and the doc states the following:

> ... This goes by declared dependencies in the pom, and there is no good log of how this graph is actually evaluated. (I was hoping to render the actual execution graph, but never got around to finding a cool tool/way to do it - plaintext ascii in the -X log would be one option).

I am wondering if such a rendition exists already and if so, how can it be triggered?